# Ghoshscript error : Error: /rangecheck in --.dicttomark--

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript, docsplit

I am trying to use ghoshscript to convert a pdf in image.

The PDF is : http://www.coppernet.zm/MPLS.pdf

```
$ sudo docsplit images -o /tmp/previews -p 1-5 -s 150,750,1000 -f png MPLS.pdf 
While reading gs_cidfm.ps:
Error: /rangecheck in --.dicttomark--
Operand stack:
   (gs_cidfm.ps)   1   --nostringval--   1   Arial   --dict:4/4(G)--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:956/1123(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:64/200(L)--   --dict:956/1123(G)--       --dict:8/14(G)--   --dict:1/1(G)--
Current allocation mode is global
Current file position is 4622
Unrecoverable error: undefined in .uninstallpagedevice
Operand stack:
    gs_cidfm.ps  1  --nostringval--  1  Arial  --nostringval--
gm convert: "gs" "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=pnmraw" "- dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4" "-r150x150" "-dFirstPage=1" "-dLastPage=1" " sOutputFile=/tmp/d20121211-1674-zs83qu/gme03xr0" "--" "/tmp/d20121211-1674-zs83qu/gmcjhLqq" "-c" "quit".
gm convert: Postscript delegate failed (MPLS.pdf).
```

I tryied to apply this : http://thomas-genin.com/ghostscript-convert-error-undefined-in-findresource/ and it creates this error.

**EDIT:** If I remove the `/var/lib/ghostscript/fonts/cidfmap` file I don't have the error anymore.

```
1 /Arial << /FileType /TrueType /Path (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arial.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Artifex) (Unicode) 0] >> ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of Ghostscript you are using, and because you are using something which executes Ghostscript you haven't given me a command line I can actually try.

However, on the assumption that the (ImageMagick?) command line in the error is the one being used, I rendered your PDF file to PNM without problems using a copy of the current code, so I suspect that this is resolved, I would recommend you upgrade to the current version.

If this doesn't solve the problem, then you should open a bug report at http://bugs.ghostscript.com please attach the PDF file there, and supply a Ghostscript command line which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It is the 8.71 version. The pdf works without the arial cidfmap but fail with it.

Comment: 8.71 is quite old, 2.5 years old roughly, I would suggest you upgrade to the current version, 9.06. If the problem persists then please open a bug report. For me, using your command line on a current version of the source works.